# "Directory or file does not exist" while cloning repo and moving files in alpine docker on kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, alpine-linux, rancher, persistent-volumes

I am trying to initialize my container but I keep on getting `directory or file does not exist` error on the following script. I essentially need to get config files from repo into the folder.

I am not looking for alternative solutions by placing the exact file, I need this to be a solution for an arbitrary number of files.

Looking into the alpine docker, the `/usr/share` folder should exist.

This is the `initContainer` used:

```yaml
      initContainers:
        - name: init-config
          image: alpine/git
          command:
            - "git clone https://github.com/coolacid/docker-misp.git /usr/repo && cp -a /usr/repo/docker-misp/server-configs/ /usr/share"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share
              name: misp-app-config
```

How do I properly move the files into a volume?

Edit 1: I am using the `alpine/git` image.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? And don't litter your question with "Edit:" sections. If anyone cares, they can browse the edit history. Also, include how you run this and what output you get, not just a snippet of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend using:

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["git clone https://github.com/coolacid/docker-misp.git /usr/repo && cp -a /usr/repo/server-configs/ /usr/share"]
```

instead of:

```
command:
            - "git clone https://github.com/coolacid/docker-misp.git /usr/repo && cp -a /usr/repo/docker-misp/server-configs/ /usr/share"
```

Additionally, you shouldn't specify the `docker-misp` directory as all the contents of the `docker-misp.git` repository have been cloned  to `/usr/repo`:

```
# git clone https://github.com/coolacid/docker-misp.git /usr/repo
Cloning into '/usr/repo'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 905, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (160/160), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Total 905 (delta 144), reused 136 (delta 136), pack-reused 745
Receiving objects: 100% (905/905), 152.64 KiB | 2.50 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (444/444), done.

# ls /usr/repo
LICENSE  README.md  build-docker-compose.yml  docker-compose.yml  examples  modules  server  server-configs
```

---

I've prepared an example to illustrate how it works:
**NOTE:** I used [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) but you probably want to use a different [type of volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#volume-types):

```
$ cat app-1.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: app-1
  name: app-1
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: init-config
      image: alpine/git
      command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
      args: ["git clone https://github.com/coolacid/docker-misp.git /usr/repo && cp -a /usr/repo/server-configs/ /usr/share"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share
          name: misp-app-config
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: web-1
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/work-dir"
      name: misp-app-config
  volumes:
  - name: misp-app-config
    emptyDir: {}
    
$ kubectl apply -f app-1.yml
pod/app-1 created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-1   1/1     Running   0          11s
```

We can check if the `server-configs` directory has been copied to the `web-1` Pod:

```
$ kubectl exec -it app-1 -- sh
Defaulted container "web-1" out of: web-1, init-config (init)
# ls /work-dir
server-configs
# ls /work-dir/server-configs
email.php
```

As you can see in the example above, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning the repository content to `/usr/repo`.
So your copy command should be

`cp -a /usr/repo/server-configs/ /usr/share`